# php: compare UUID and strings

Tags: php, uuid

The following code is not working:

```
if ($entryByPhaseID["activity_ID"] == "50e5cde678bf94.62826693")
                        {
                            echo $entryByPhaseID["activity_ID"]. "<BR>";
                            $DIB = $DIB + $entryByPhaseID["net_value"]; 
                        }
```

I am trying to compare a UUID retrieved with a query $entryByPhaseID["activity_ID"] with the string representation of it. I never see the echo message... Can you help? Thank you.

Comment: To debug, add `var_dump($entryByPhaseID["activity_ID"]);` before your `if` line to see its value.

Comment: Thank you Pang. The error was in a previous if statement where I used = instead of ==. Your suggestion point me in the right direction.

Comment: Glad to help. [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) is very useful in debugging. You can even use `var_dump($entryByPhaseID);` do dump everything in the array. :-)